# How to set a variable in an AngularJS callback?

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS 1.5 directive:

```
var assetSearchService = function(proService) {
    var assets = [];

    var searchAssets = function(searchTerm){
        proService.searchAssets(searchTerm).then(function(data){
            assets = data.data;
        });
    };

    return {
        searchAssets, searchAssets,
        assets: assets
    };
};
```

When I try to use `assetSearchService.assets` in my controller after calling search, the data is not set in `assetService.assets`.

If I log the data after the `searchAssets` promise returns, I am getting data.

`this.assets` does not work so how do I do get the variable back from the callback?

Comment: instead of *replacing* `assets` inside your callback, you should be pushing the data into the existing array.  try `assets = assets.concat(data.data);`

Comment: No, assets does not reference the originally declared `var assets`.

Comment: it does, but you are replacing it inside the callback with a different array, which breaks the angular bindings

Comment: I tried it your way, and even tried your way with dumping the whole service with a `$timeout` and the assets are never assigned to the original `var assets`

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer.  Neither `assets = newArray` nor `conact` does not work because both return a new array and break the reference, rather than modifying the current one.

This works:

`Array.prototype.push.apply(assets, data.data);`

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mbaranski/5k4bqo0z/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve more complex solution

```
var assetSearchService = function(proService) {
  service = this;
  service.assets = [];

  service.searchAssets = function(searchTerm){
    proService.searchAssets(searchTerm).then(function(data){
        assets.push(data.data);
    });
  };

  return service;
};
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, because the whole problem is emptying the `assets` array and adding each item from `data.data` to the new array.